# Question about graphing reciprocals of cubic functions

Tags: functions, polynomials, graphing-functions

Suppose you needed to graph the reciprocal of a cubic function by hand. Could you do this by finding the asymptotes, taking the reciprocal of each point (or a sufficient amount of points) and then drawing the curve through? If not, is there a counterexample where this process wouldn't be possible?

Comment: As you are graphing by hand; how precisely do you want to graph it? What characteristics, qualitatively and quantitatively, do you want it to represent faithfully?

Comment: And indeed the only thing that comes to my mind is to compute some values of the cubic and taking their reciprocals. Its asymptotes are easy; verticals at the roots of the cubic, and a horizontal ar $0$.